# How do I properly alias a module in RequireJS on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS on my Node.js server to aid in code re-use. I'm sharing modules between client and server, and therefore I want to keep these modules as general as possible.

The problem is that I have a 3rd party library (easeljs) that provides both a client and a server-side implementation, with the server-side implementation provided by npm as 'node-easel'.

The way I expected to deal with this doesn't work. I provided a paths config for the server side application as follows:

```
requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire: require,
    paths: { 
        'easeljs': 'node-easel'
    }    
})
```

The above code will first look for `node-easel.js` in the root directory, before falling back onto node's `require('easeljs')`, which is not what I want. I want requireJS to fall back onto `require('node-easel')`. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe the map config will work better than paths - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map

Comment: No, unfortunately that will have the exact same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled a little with this myself, but actually was able to use a combination of RequireJS `map` configuration and a NPM module loader. The code is as follows:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        npm: 'helpers/requirejs/npmloader'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            dust: 'npm!dustjs-linkedin'
        }
    }
});
```

And then for `helpers/requirejs/npmloader.js`:

```
define({
    normalize: function (name, normalize) {
        return name;
    },
    load: function (name, req, onload, config) {
        require(name);
    }
});
```

With this you can easily alias NodeJS modules using RequireJS.

In `package.json` I also use the following:

```
"main": "./bin/server.js",
"bin": {
    "server.js": "./bin/server.js"
 }
```

With top level `bin/server,js` being a symbolic link to `build/init.js` and being executable `chmod a+x build/server.js`.

Instead of using the `amdefine` loader, which is rather lacking without the ability to use plugins, I use the full `requirejs` module with NodeJS, and then I just have `define` be available globally for all my modules as you can see in the code below.

Then `src/init.js` (or after building - `build/init.js`) contains the following which might be a useful example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * @file The AMD loader module configuration.
 * @author runelabs <http://github.com/runelabs>
 * @version $Id$
 * @description
 *
 * MODULE 'init' OVERVIEW:
 * This defines the init RequireJS configuration module,
 * in contrast to other modules which are using the AMD define() pattern.
 *
 */
/*global require, define, global*/ // using JShint linter

(function() {
    'use strict';
    var requirejs, mocha, mainProg;
    global.requirejs = global.define = requirejs = require('requirejs');
    mainProg = ['main'];
    var config = {
        deps:              mainProg,
        paths: {
            lib:           'lib/',
            tests:         '../tests',
            app:           '.',
            config:        'models/config', 
            packages:      'packages',
            logger:        'packages/logger/logger',
            pkg:           'helpers/requirejs/pkgloader',
            npm:           'helpers/requirejs/npmloader',
            text:          'lib/requirejs-text/text'
            /* ... more paths */
        },
        map: {
            '*': {
                marionette:'npm!backbone.marionette',
                dust:      'npm!dustjs-linkedin'
            }
        }
    };
    requirejs.config(config);
    requirejs.onError = function (err, u, l) {
        var LOG = require('./packages/logger/logger');
        LOG.error('RequireJS error: ', err.requireType);
        LOG.error('   mod: ', err.requireModules);
        LOG.error('   map: ', err.requireMap);
        if (err.requireType === 'timeout') {
            LOG.error('   modules: ', err.requireModules);
        }
        LOG.error('ERR: ', err);
        LOG.error('ERR error: ', err.error);
        LOG.error('ERR type: ', typeof err);
        if (err['toSource']) {
            LOG.error('ERR src: ', err.toSource());
        }
        LOG.error('ERR name: ', err.name);
        LOG.error('ERR message: ', err.message);
        LOG.error('ERR file: ', err.fileName);
        LOG.error('ERR line: ', err.lineNumber);
        LOG.error('ERR col: ', err.columnNumber);
        LOG.error('ERR stack: ', err.stack);
        throw(err);
    };
})();
```

Hope this helps someone else looking to use RequireJS to load stuff from `node_modules`.

EDIT: A smaller example is from RequireJS creator James Burke at:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/requirejs/ur_UQLr04rc/sSpM8y87VNMJ